# Adding Google Cast SDK to 64-bit build

Tags: ios, 64-bit, google-cast

Trying to build a universal 32/64-bit binary with the Google Cast framework (2.0 from [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/downloads/GoogleCastFramework-2.0-Release.zip)) produces this warning and several linker errors:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file [...]GoogleCast.framework/GoogleCast, 
missing required architecture x86_64 in file
[...]GoogleCast.framework/GoogleCast (3 slices)

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCKDeviceManager", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in GoogleCastDeviceController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCKDeviceScanner", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in GoogleCastDeviceController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCKImage", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in GoogleCastDeviceController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCKMediaControlChannel", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in GoogleCastDeviceController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCKMediaInformation", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in GoogleCastDeviceController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCKMediaMetadata", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in GoogleCastDeviceController.o
  "_kGCKMetadataKeySubtitle", referenced from: [...]
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Google was about three months late [adding 64-bit support for Analytics](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=356), so I'm wondering if they've delayed the release of a 64-bit Cast framework as well.

Has anyone successfully built a 64-bit binary with this framework?

Comment: I'll see what I can find out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  We are working on it.

Comment: Any update on this? Unable to deploy to iPad Air.

Comment: The Google Cast SDK supports iOS as follows:

- 32-bit only currently
- iOS version 6 and later

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes) for 2.1.0.529 (released 3/25/2014):

> 64-bit builds are now fully supported

I updated the Google Cast framework in my project and was able to deploy to iPad Air and iPhone 5S.

The latest framework is available [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads) ([direct link](https://developers.google.com/cast/downloads/GoogleCastFramework-2.1.0-Release.zip)).